# TypeScript generic that embeds another generic

Tags: typescript, function, generics

I'm doing some general data transformations on objects that have a similar shape and have now run into a case where I can't infer the type of an "embedded" generic.

This is what I have:

```
function transform<
  TObject extends {
    items: TItem[];
  },
  TItem extends {
    status: 'ok' | 'loading' | 'error';
  }
>(obj: TObject) {
  const items = obj.items.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    $isOk: item.status === 'ok',
  }));
  const $numOk = obj.items.reduce(
    (sum, item) => sum + (item.status === 'ok' ? 1 : 0),
    0,
  );
  const $numTotal = obj.items.length;

  return {
    ...obj,
    items,
    $numOk,
    $numTotal,
  };
}
```

I then expect to be able to use items in the same shape as I send them in, like this:

```
const obj = transform({
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      status: 'ok',
    },
  ],
  id: 314,
  name: 'hello',
});

console.log('numTotal', obj.id) // yay
console.log('numTotal', obj.$numTotal) // yay

for (const item of obj.items) {
  console.log('item', item);
  console.log('$isOk?', item.$isOk);
  // ❌ Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ id: number; status: "ok"; } | ({ status: "ok" | "loading" | "error"; } & { $isOk: boolean; })'.
  console.log('$isOk?', item.id);
  // ❌ Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ id: number; status: "ok"; } | ({ status: "ok" | "loading" | "error"; } & { $isOk: boolean; })'.
}
```

However, the type of the items isn't inferred the whole way through. Is there a workaround to achieve similar results or have I hit a limitation in TypeScript?

Full example to play around with [on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=39&ssc=58&pln=39&pc=1#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-Gw-1QACgNQEC9nYcDSkg9NoJsWDrXgw5EIwZDCIwrCcLwroUMNNDUGImiPIo7w-C8uiQgYpzWNgi9JlQbjeKgfjBNAcUgA).

Comment: By the way, *THANK YOU* for the playground link.  Questions with a link to a [mcve] in a web IDE are so much easier to address than those without.

Comment: . It's very hard to help someone who doesn't make it easy for you to help them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the compiler is not being as specific as you want it to be when evaluating the type of a spread object like `{...item, $isOk: true}` or `{...obj, items}`.  You need to help it along:

```
function transform<
  O extends { items: Array<{ status: 'ok' | 'loading' | 'error' }> }>
  (obj: O) {
  const items = obj.items.map((item) => ({
    ...(item as O['items'][number]),
    $isOk: item.status === 'ok',
  }));
  const $numOk = obj.items.reduce(
    (sum, item) => sum + (item.status === 'ok' ? 1 : 0),
    0,
  );
  const $numTotal = obj.items.length;

  return {
    ...(obj as Omit<O, "items">),
    items,
    $numOk,
    $numTotal,
  };
}
```

First I've made just one generic parameter `O` representing the object passed in, which is hopefully enough to infer the entire structure.

Then, for the first spread we have to tell the compiler that `item` is of type `O['items'][number]` (meaning: if `n` is a `number`, then it's the type of `obj.items[n]`).  Otherwise the compiler unhelpfully widens it all the way to `{ status: 'ok' | 'loading' | 'error' }`, which is true but not useful to you.

Finally, for the last spread, since we're overwriting the `items` property, I tell the compiler that `obj` is of type `Omit<O, "items">` (meaning: the type of `obj` as if `items` were not present).  Otherwise the compiler gives you the intersection of `O` and `{items: TheRealItemsType}`, which is not accurate enough for you.  Generic spreads are implemented as intersections (see [microsoft/TypeScript#28234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28234) for the implementation and discussion).  And intersections are *close* to what a spread does but it gets property overwrites wrong.  Doing it correctly "would take a substantial amount of work to implement this new type constructor and endow it with all the capabilities we already implement for intersection types, and it would produce little or no gain in precision for most scenarios."  So we have to do it manually.

Anyway, after this your code works as desired, I think:

```
for (const item of obj.items) {
  console.log('item', item);
  console.log('$isOk?', item.$isOk); //
  console.log('$isOk?', item.id); //
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFATgQzAZ2HFBbAHgFgAoRRAeUQFMAPKasAE00QG9EYG9MAuRAIIp0ATwIdMUNFBB9EAcjgBreYgA+CgDZw0TGGADmqjfOrDcqgL4A+RDdLkAFHABGAK34UAlOweIICJKc3KwAvIiubgB0XNQ8UXhoAA6OjrF4PqG2jmx+5FEFadyIaKwUANry6ZjyALrlYCB4Lma1XgA0eYgAJDCYFEr86VGS0rKIoZMKyvKdZHZeXgDcfgFYUD2NeAMTEe4xIVEo1EwgENSOXY6YTe3BcZm2N3iIANSIRXEjUjJhU4oqRAAfkQAEZEPwAAwdLqQubkZarQIbbpbAAqcCkml2kQOcUwUU0jAMUAAFisSH5jjIUEhcvN8oVIiUynguAQKHcAETVLnWGEM+48O5dVFNAbw8ibJoYrGSywUyykUhrILM8KoDDYXB4HJ+ar8cpdelSqUwJj8UGS02jX78AGzLqWSW1SXm-gAZlBABZJWA0HhqPbSdRNNpHSRLIjKTHVXAiYS4AZHPJ0Zi0JpZntomK8LKMz5lSQcCgPqqNukIsBs3ieD4Tf5AvHqInk1VuFn0tHyHGE9o271+kogZ3uFFBwNlogAPTTwC8G4BgPaRWGbrZTE+Ho6+5qns8XpCVJCAA)

Comment: Boom! This did the trick. A bit sad I have to jump through these hoops to solve it but glad that there are hoops I can jump through!